# R input file contains the value #NUM! I want to replace these with NA. How?

Tags: r, excel, input, character-replacement

I am reading quite a number of .csv files originating from Excel, into R. Some cells contain the value '#NUM!', which I guess results from dividing by zero. In any case, R does not like it. And since I have many files, I would like to replace the #NUM! values with NA as I import the file into R. Instead of going through every file doing seek-replace.

Suggestion is appreciated.
Thanks.

jd

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`read.csv` has an argument called `na.strings` which enables you to interpret which values shall be considered as `NA`. Try that.

Example:

```
> read.csv("nana.csv")
     X1    X2    X3
1     1 #NUM!     4
2     2     4 #NUM!
3 #NUM! #NUM! #NUM!

> read.csv("nana.csv",na.strings="#NUM!")
  X1 X2 X3
1  1 NA  4
2  2  4 NA
3 NA NA NA
```